# Как в С++ сделать, чтобы подмодули тоже могли общаться?

Tags: c++

Допустим, у меня есть главный файл main.cpp, который инклюдит main.h. В этом заголовочнике подключаются два других, при каждом них есть файлы .cpp с реализацией. Как мне сделать так, чтобы эти подмодули тоже могли общаться друг с другом и "видели" функционал друг друга?
Опишите мне пожалуйста общую структуру, где писать какой #include.

Comment: Любой файл, которому нужна какая-то сущность из хедера, инклудит этот хедер. Казалось бы, вроде все просто. Разве что нельзя допускать, чтобы хедеры инклудили друг друга по кругу.